# Why it is possible to cast any object to any interface?

Tags: java

```
class A {}
interface Wtf{}


A a = new A();
Wtf wtf = (Wtf)a;
```

What is the reason, why this is compiled just fine? Also in C# :D

Comment: Does it run without a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: No it doesn't. Not a real question.

Comment: @whatswrong: no it doesn't. At least not for me. And it should not run without an exception.

Comment: Sorry, I meant there will by Exception

Comment: So in other words when you said it *does* run without a ClassCastException you meant that it *doesn't* run without a ClassCastException. Which is in fact the answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll get a ClassCastException when you run it.

The reason it doesn't give an error when you compile it, is that a subclass of A might implement `Wtf`, like this:

```
public class A {
    interface Wtf { }

    static class B extends A implements Wtf { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        Wtf wtf = (Wtf) a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That's because `a` could also be an instance of a subclass of A which implements the interface. So the behaviour of the compiler is correct.

Answer (score 4):

This cast is allowed (at compile-time), because it *could* conceivably work.

`a` *could* actually reference an object of type `B` that is defined as `class B extends A implements Wtf`.

Of course in your case it's "just" an `A` and the cast will fail at runtime. But the compiler does not go so far in the analysis as to check that: it only checks the static type of the variable.